# Sort Arraylist containing both numbers and letters

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

This is my current arraylist:

```
ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();    

[102423;asd.com, 49952;qwe.com, 76933;rty.com, 199526;fgh.com, 139388;jkl, 25114;qaz, 155766;ghj.com, 321339;vbn.com, 210513;kol.com]
```

And I want to sort them by the numbers. Ive tried following:

```
Collections.sort(myArrayList)
for(String counter : myArrayList){
   System.out.println(counter);
  }
```

But its not working. Im thinking splitting then do Collections.sort but then I dont know how I will pair them togehter again.

Comment: it's a list of objects **List<Object>** ?

Comment: Post your List declaration

Comment: My list is `ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();`  Do you recommend ` List<Object> ` instead?

Comment: "It's not working" is not an adequate description of a problem.

Comment: No it's ok .. just implement Comparator () to compare only the number part interface and pass it as a second argument in the Collections.sort() method (you don"t have to pair them together after comparaison)

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) static method and supply a custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) whose [`compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) method extracts the numeric prefix from the two elements and only compares those prefixes.

You could use [`String.split(";")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) to get the numeric prefix, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Use comparator like below :

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o1.split(";")[0].compareTo(o2.split(";")[0]);
    }
}
```

Your sorting code would be just about like you wrote:

```
Collections.sort(arrayList, new CustomComparator());
```

Comment: this won't work. you are considering whole string. You need to split the strings first and only consider their 1st part.

Comment: Do I make a new class?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is that you have declared `ArrayList` of `String`s. So, `Collections.sort(YourArrayList)` will sort it lexicographicall. So,you have to write your own `Comparator` to read the String and interpret it and compare.

So, Try this.

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
        "102423;asd.com", "49952;qwe.com", "76933;rty.com",
        "199526;fgh.com", "139388;jkl", "25114;qaz",
        "155766;ghj.com", "321339;vbn.com", "210513;kol.com");
    List<String> sorted = list.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> String.format("%0" + (20 - s.indexOf(';')) + "d%s", 0, s)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (String s : sorted)
        System.out.println(s);
```

result is

```
25114;qaz
49952;qwe.com
76933;rty.com
102423;asd.com
139388;jkl
155766;ghj.com
199526;fgh.com
210513;kol.com
321339;vbn.com
```

This code sort list internally

```
00000000000000102423;asd.com
00000000000000049952;qwe.com
00000000000000076933;rty.com
00000000000000199526;fgh.com
00000000000000139388;jkl
00000000000000025114;qaz
00000000000000155766;ghj.com
00000000000000321339;vbn.com
00000000000000210513;kol.com
```